Are observations of different plots of the same farmer independent for a chi-squared test?
I have a pretty basic question. I have a dataset that has surveyed say 1000 farmers and their demographic data, and also surveyed the agricultural practices they undertake on each of their plots. Only a few farmers have more than one plot, with a total of maybe 1100 plots. I want to run a log linear analysis to see if the practices undertaken are related to each other or are independent.
How do I deal with multiple plots from the same farmer? Do these count as independent because they are separate plots? I want to do a logistic model later to see if demographics impact the practices undertaken, so I feel like it would not make sense to start with a test assuming the plots are independent. If these are not independent, should I select one plot per farmer at random, or the plot with maximum practice adoption? Or should I remove all multiple entry farmers and plots completely? I would lose quite some data this way. What is a solid reasoning to use?
Edit: The practices are binary variables, like use of Input A (Yes/No), use of Input B (Yes/No), Conservation Tillage (Yes/No) and so on. I plan to look at 3 main such practices, and see if their adoption depends on each other.

You could use some random effects model with a random intercept for each farmer, that is a way of representing dependence. To say more I think you need to tell us some more, for instance, how many/what are the different "practices"

Okay, thank you! Have added some more details, let me know if more are needed.
